# Contacts name are not showing in Inbox in my kotlin/android code

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-manifest

I have written code in kotlin for offline SMS app.It shows Company messages along their names(ZONG,UFONE..),but it is showing my contact numbers not their names.Whats I do so their names display instead of their contact numbers. [image: **Screenshot of app running on mobile**]

As you can see in this screenshot the Company names are showing but Contact names are not.

I have searched too but found nothing.Please help me how to solve this.

```
 class Inbox : AppCompatActivity(){

    private val requestReceiveSms: Int =1
    private val requestReadSms: Int = 2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.readsms)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
                requestReadSms
            )
        } else {
            refreshSmsInbox()

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        if(requestCode == requestReadSms) refreshSmsInbox()
    }

private fun refreshSmsInbox() {

        val smsList = ArrayList<SmsData>()

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null)

        if(cursor!!.moveToFirst()){

            val nameID = cursor.getColumnIndex("address")

            val messageID = cursor.getColumnIndex("body")

            val dateID = cursor.getColumnIndex("date")

            do{

                val dateString = cursor.getString(dateID)

                smsList.add(SmsData(cursor.getString(nameID),cursor.getString(messageID),Date(dateString.toLong()).toString()))
            }while (cursor.moveToNext())

        }

        cursor.close()

        val  adapter = ListAdapter(this, smsList)

        sms_list_view.adapter = adapter
    }


}
```

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView

        android:id="@+id/sms_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        tools:ignore="Suspicious0dp"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**XML FILE 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/sms_sender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sms_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/sms_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Expected**

Show Contact names which are saved in mobile.

**Actual Result**

Contact numbers displayed instead of contact names.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code to get contact name:-

```
fun getContactName(context: Context, phoneNumber: String): String? {
    var contactName: String? = null
    val uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber))
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
    cursor?.let {
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            contactName = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME))
        }
        it.close()
    }
    return contactName;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `cursor.getString(0)` you could use specific column name like `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME))`